# How to setup HILT DI in layer base multi-module android application

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, clean-architecture, use-case, android-module

I am creating an Android Application based on Clean Archtecture with App Modularization.

I have modularized the app by 4 layers (:presentation, :domain:, :data, commons).
The required hierarchy is as follows

1. :presentation can access :commons + :domain
2. :domain can access :commons
3. :data can access :commons + :domain
4. :commons access no other module

**Problem?**

I have added The HILT MODULE in :data module as it belongs there because of dependency nature. It implements the RestaurantRepository Interface defined in :domain module.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataDependenciesModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRestaurantRepository(
        api: RestaurantApi,
        localCacheRepository: LocalCacheRepository,
        database: MealBookingDatabase
    ): RestaurantRepository {
        return RestaurantRepositoryImpl(api, localCacheRepository, database)
    }
```

Below is the UseCase which uses/requires this dependency is inside :domain module (Ofcourse UseCases lies in :domain modue), but the dependency is not accessible there.

```
class GetRestaurants @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: RestaurantRepository,
) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(
        fetchFromApi: Boolean,
    ): Flow<Resource<List<Restaurant>>> {
        return repository.getRestaurants(fetchFromApi)
    }
}
```

**Possible Soltuions**

1. make :domain module include :data module, hence :data stuff can be accessible in :domain. (Can't do that, as :data already depends on :domain, it will generate a circular dependency)
2. Add HILT MODULE and entire Dependency Injection stuff in :presentation and make :presentation include :data module (to create dependencies). I believe it is a bad approach as this way we will be exposing :data to :presentation, and :presentation clearly doesn't needs to have access to whats happening inside :data.
3. Include DI in commons, and include commons in all modules, but how can we do that :commons will also require to include classes which are in other modules to create them.

**What is Required?**

Make RestaurantRepository accessible in GetRestaurants Use Case inside :domain, maybe any Interceptor can be created here which i don't have any idea about.

What is the best approach to handle this type of Dependency Injection requirement?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by including hilt modules in `:app` module as it includes all modules you defined.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a must to create DI dir in :data, meaning like

1. :data
2. :domain
3. :presentation
4. :di

DI can also have a dir in their hierarchy.
`api: RestaurantApi, localCacheRepository: LocalCacheRepository, database: MealBookingDatabase` 
all of these parameters should be singleton injectables similar to the.
`@Module @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) object DataDependenciesModule.` 
And this class of yours `RestaurantRepositoryImpl` will have an injectable constructor.
Then after all that when you inject your interface in GetRestaurants use case it will be available.
Just a tip any injectable that is to be placed in Usecase can have ViewModelComponent. Hope it helps